# Scroll only a div horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I need is to have a div with a background-image and another .png image that will scroll horizontally. http://prntscr.com/9d0d25

I need the background to stay fixed and cars X and Z to move horizontally to the right on scroll down (and back to the left on scroll up.
When the cars are out of sight I want the website to proceed to scrolling vertically to the other content of the website (as well as when scrolling up to scroll the div with the .png horizontally back)

The html structure is something like this:

```
<div class="bgimage"> // has a background in css
   <div class="cars">
      <img src="images/cars.png" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="othercontent">
</div>
```

But I have almost no experience in javascript so I have no idea how to implement that.

(I googled parallax, but found examples only for entirely horizontal or vertical websites, which weren't very responsive"

Comment: Sounds like some sort of parallax, where you bind to the scroll event, and move stuff on the screen based on the users scrolling. This probably isn't the easiest thing to do if you have no idea how to write javascript, and this isn't a coding service where people write code for you ?

Comment: @adeneo sorry I didn't meant someone to write code for me, just a few instructions if anyone knows how. And I can write javascript, I'm just new to it, so I don't know most of the things I should for this :\

Comment: I'll help you a little bit on the way -> http://jsfiddle.net/3gn6abq8/

Comment: @adeneo It's me again, well I've came to this: http://jsfiddle.net/denea/3gn6abq8/7/

Which works perfect for what I need, but I need a little more help, if you're not busy.
It scrolls inside the `home div` when I hover it, but doesn't when I hover the `cars or buttons divs`, is there a way to place multiple divs instead of `$('#home') ... ` ?
Is there a way to make `buttons and cars divs` relative as soon as `#homeinner` is done scrolling, besides `if height is > *** px`, because I want to have the layout responsive ?

Thanks in advance, Denis.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jquery you can use `$(window).on('scroll', function(){})` to watch for scroll event

Here's a simple one I did:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       //Scrolling Down
       $('.cars').css('left',st + "px");
   } else {
      //Scrolling Up
      $('.cars').css('left', st + "px");
   }       
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OpuLance/8pz821zt/)

Answer (score 0):

On mousewheel movement

```
    var mouseWheelEvt = function (event) {
    if (document.body.doScroll)
        document.body.doScroll(event.wheelDelta>0?"left":"right");
    else if ((event.wheelDelta || event.detail) > 0)
        document.body.scrollLeft -= 10;
    else
        document.body.scrollLeft += 10;

    return false;
}
document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheelEvt);
```